# AWS RDS: How to Connect to Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I just set up an Amazon RDS instance.  I have a separate application server and I am trying to figure out how to connect to the RDS instance from my EC2 application server. On the Instance page, I have

```
enbdpoint: mycompany.czdv3mj7ps25.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

I tried to login into to psql using that address but I got

```
$ psql -h mycompany.czdv3mj7ps25.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 -U myuser -d mydb
psql: could not translate host name "mycompany.czdv3mj7ps25.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432" to address: Name or service not known
```

How do I connect to the instances database?  I don't see any other ip addresses in the RDS console.

Comment: Looks like this is rather lower level than PostgreSQL its self. Check `dig +trace theaddress` to see where it's failing to resolve.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have wrong syntax. The correct syntax is:

```
$ psql --host mycompany.czdv3mj7ps25.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port 5432 --username myuser --dbname mydb
```

You have specified `port` information wrong in you command. the port has to be specified using `--port`  option and not `hostname:port`

Comment: Thanks, thats right, total brain fart on my end, thanks.  Also --host can be -h --username can be -U and --dbname can be -d

Comment: I know. I always prefer descriptive names rather than a single alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me in the psql command line:

**\connect dbname username hostname port#**

If the information is correct it will take a couple seconds to process then it will ask for your password

Also make sure the security group for your instance, the outbound/inbound is setup to allow access from your IP